# Are there electrical methods to make noise without a loudspeaker?

Tags: sound

I am designing a toy that needs to provide an audible response to an action, but I do not want to use a small loudspeaker.

Is there any other way of creating a sound? For instance, filling a chamber with air to several atmospheres then letting it "pop" with a valve would be perfect (or the reverse) and give some great tactile response as well - but too many moving parts. I also like the sound of a flash charging up and discharging - maybe some (safe) way to create this effect writ large?

Comment: This is more of a mechanical engineering problem if you don't want to use a speaker

Comment: rather than telling us what cannot or don't want to use, maybe instead actually tell us the constraints. What's the maximum size in mm × mm × mm of the device?

Comment: Look up singing tesla coils.

Comment: And why don't you want to use a speaker which was made to do exactly what it is that you want to do? Without constraints it just sounds like a misguided preference and no meaningful recommendations can be provided because we have no idea what limitation it is that you're trying to work around.

Comment: All sound requires a momentary or continous diaphragm vibration. So a speaker is a diaphragm of metal/plastic/paper/carbon fiber. you could try a bell or a spring based energy system?

Comment: Wind-up and purely motor-driven toys have long had such features. Monkeys banging cymbals, screeching created mechanically and such like. Even Chatty Cathy (a doll) originally had a spring-driven pull cord voicebox.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a noticeable physical effect in little space, there is really no point in trying to use something not intended to produce a noticeable physical effect in little space.  And you want this thing to be efficient in order to fit additional required circuitry and the necessary energy source for powering it into this small space as well.

There are quite small piezo buzzers or "speakers" (obviously there is very little low-frequency response to be expected) that you can put on a PCB.

Comment: Piezo is the only practical way 4 sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a solenoid to hit against something, this was used in pinball games to make a loud knock sound to indicate some goal was reached such as winning a free game.

Answer (score 0):

Haptics work well for this. They take up very little space but can make a good deal of noise when attached to a plastic housing. They’re driven like speakers (they have a voice coil and armature) so can represent sounds as well as physical sensations.

You can also consider a metal-disc ‘buzzer’ as a cheesy speaker. These have a coil that actuates a metal diaphragm. They’re also driven like speakers. Real world example: I did an RF4CE remote control to make a ‘finder’ tone. Admittedly it sounds like crap (tinny, literally), but it did the job, again in very little space. Very inexpensive.

Comment: disc buzzers are often driven single-ended (positive waveform only)  you can play a recognisable melody but they often don't work well for speech.

Comment: Yes, they only really work with unipolar drive. Cheep and cheerful.

Answer (score 0):

It has "speaker" in its name but it works quite differently: [Electrostatic Speaker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_loudspeaker).

However, I don't know small they could be.